# Taking tar -tf output and putting it into a java jtree

Tags: java, tree, tar, jtree

I want to take the output of a tar -tf which is a long directory listing for linux filesystem and put it into a java jtree.

The problem I am running into is how to get the hierarchy correct.  The root node is easy but how do I add the other nodes to the tree in the proper place?  I believe it would involve finding the parent node in the tree.

So far I am using DefaultMutableTreeNode as the root and creating a new one for each node.  I created a custom object overriding toString to give the name of the directory or file, a getPath that returns the full path to it and getParent which is the full path without the name on the end.

Comment: Thought about it some more and came up with this:  What i need to do is start at the root node and get a specific child, then get a specific child of that one.   I have figured out that i can split my path on the / to get hierarchy for the children. But now I am stuck at what data structure can do this.  DefaultMutableTreeNode operates as an array and in all of the examples i've seen the node is added to the JTree after the entire tree is build.  So is there a treemodel that uses a hashtable for the children>

Answer (score 2):

The article [*Understanding the TreeModel*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/) may offer some guidance on modeling hierarchical files in a `TreeModel` suitable for use with `JTree`.